# Datepicker material Ui outline variant

Tags: material-ui

For textfield and select, i see we have below option to add variant="outlined".
But,  i don't see for material-ui/DatePicker. Can someone suggest how to add varaint to datepicker api using material UI?

Answer (score 75):

You can use `inputVariant="outlined"`

Comment: `inputVariant` does not exist un this documentation : https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/.
Is it specific to a version of mui ?

Answer (score 7):

you can add slotProps like this:

```
slotProps={{ textField: { variant: "standard" } }}
```

to your TimePicker element

Answer (score 1):

Outlined variants were added in 3.1.0 whereas DatePicker was removed before 1.0.

Comment: ok. Do we have any api for date field with outlined variant ?